# CMake's VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT doesn't work for RelWithDebInfo

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have the following cmake line to set the debugger environment in Visual Studio.

```
set_property(TARGET Jing PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "DATA_DIR=data-xyz" )
```

This works fine for Release and Debug configurations in Visual Studio. But not for RelWithDebInfo. I tried generator expressions but they seemed to be ignored.

Cmake 3.25.2. Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.5).